# Как сделать эффект тени у Grid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Не могу нигде найти как сделать эффект отбрасывания тени у Grid для Visual studio 2015 UWP [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А `DropShadowEffect` в UWP недоступен?

Comment: Вроде я пробовал, не получается...

Comment: А что значит «не получается» конкретно? Не компилируется? Компилируется, но не показывает тень? Какие параметры?

Comment: @VladD Я добавил скриншот